Linear Algebra, subvector space criterion
I am wondering why is the zero vector used to show the non-emptyness of a vector subspace.
Is there any intutive way to understand this?

There are two reasons.
First of all the zero vector must necessarily be contained in a vector space. So if there is a vector to check it should be the $0$ vector.
If $0$ is already not contained in the set in question, you can already stop.
If you would show that the set is nonempty, you can do some work which goes nowhere anyways. It is a much more reliable criterion.
And if you do not check the zero you have to take an elaborate guess of a different choice. It is most natural to go for the $0$.
Secondly, it is way the easiest to prove (or disprove). Normaly it should take 5 seconds to prove if $0$ is in your set, or not.
